# GitHub images not loading on pages

Tags: html, github, github-pages, project, github-flavored-markdown

I created a project and uploaded the images of project to the repository.i used a div and HTML IMG tag to display image in README.md file. I provided the url of my images in repository to IMG tag. I am able to see images being loaded in preview of pages in my repository but I can't see the images on the hosted GitHub pages.
I tried the same code for another markdown file in one of my other project and it works perfectly.

Below project details

The code I used to load images in README.md:

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <img src="https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/Song-Inventory-code/blob/main/Demo/Mainpage.png" alt="Mainpage" width="400" height="300"/>
  <img src="https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/Song-Inventory-code/blob/main/Demo/Database.png" alt="Database" width="400" height="300"/>
</div>
```

Image folder link : [click here](https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/Song-Inventory-code/tree/main/Demo)

My project repository: [click here](https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/Song-Inventory-code)

Project GitHub page: [click here](https://malhar-girgaonkar.github.io/Song-Inventory-code/)

Project I used same code at but is working perfectly is given below

Code I used to load images in README.md  and works :

```
<div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/M.U.R.A.L/master/App%20data/Demo/Application%20Screenshot/Screenshot%202024-02-04%20003258.png" alt="Mainpage 1" width="400" height="300"/>
  <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/M.U.R.A.L/master/App%20data/Demo/Application%20Screenshot/Screenshot%202024-02-04%20003434.png" alt="Mainpage 2" width="400" height="300"/>
</div>
```

Image folder link : [click here](https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/M.U.R.A.L/tree/main/App%20data/Demo/Application%20Screenshot)

Project repository : [click here](https://github.com/Malhar-Girgaonkar/M.U.R.A.L)

Project GitHub page : [click here](https://malhar-girgaonkar.github.io/M.U.R.A.L/)

Your help would be appreciated. :)

I tried changing path in IMG tag to absolute link then raw link but problem of images loading in preview and not on actual page still persists.

Comment: Please show your code, it is very hard to debug based only on images

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: The "images" you're attempting to serve from the base `github.com` domain are not actually images; the resources that are returned to the client at those URLs are full HTML pages. Your second example uses `https://raw.githubusercontent.com`, which responds with the raw contents of the image file itself, which is why that works but your first example does not. It's not clear how you reached the conclusion that these two examples should function the same as one another when you're referencing these files in two completely different ways.

Comment: Thanks to clarify the difference.I was unclear as I am a newbie to GitHub. Thanks for your help

Comment: @esqew / MalharGirgaonkar: Please post and accept the answer - respectively. That will remove it from the unanswered pool.

Comment: @ScottWelker As far as I’m concerned, the question itself is due to a typo and should be closed as such; I don’t believe this necessarily holds much value to future visitors.

Comment: @esqew noted. Thank you. I'll 'flag' it as such.